# AngularFireAuth redirect issue with angular routing guard

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular-router-guards

Dear stackoverflow community,

i have the following issue. I try to use FirebaseAuthentication together with Angular7 and im trying to secure routes with guards so only logged in users can for example visit the */profile* url.

My login (*login.component.ts*) looks like this. At first I import **AngularFireAuth** and use it for logging in with Google, Facebook or Email. In the **ngOnInit** method I am subscribing to the **authState** so I can redirect to user. This is all working fine.

[image: login.component.ts]

In the next step I wanted to write an **AuthGuard** for the */profile* url so only logged in users can visit their profile. The non logged in users should be redirected to */login* first.

[image: app-routing.module.ts]

My **AuthGuard** (*auth.guard.ts*) looks like this and is using a class **AuthService** (*auth.service.ts*) internally. This **AuthService** is injected and offers a method **isAuthenticated**. If the user is authenticated he should be presented with his profile, otherwise the **AuthGuard** should return false and redirect him to login.

[image: AuthGuard]

The **AuthService** looks like this and its method **isAuthenticated** should return true if the user is logged in and false otherwise.

[image: AuthService]

If i don't add this dummy *return true* at the end of the function he will always redirect me back to */login* also when I am logged in. He also tells me that the function has no return value

[image: error. function needs a return value]

So I know that this subscription is not enough in the **isAuthenticated** method but I am curious what the best solution would look like to detect if the user is logged in.

If one of you has a best practice type of solution it would be very nice if he could show me. There are not very many proper tutorials out there.

In the meantime I will try to keep looking for a solution on google. I hope someone of you can help me with this problem. Thank you :)

best regards
Jan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

subscription cannot return value.

you can use map instead of subscribe.

```
return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(map((res) => {
   if (res && res.uid)
      return true;

   return false;
});
```

also change the return value signature of isAuthenticated Method from `boolean` to `Observable<boolean>` or `Observable<boolean> | boolean`

Answer (score 3):

I already used Angular FireAuth to implement the same thing as yours and here is what I came up with: 

**Function isAuthenticated ie isLoggedIn**

```js
public isLoggedIn() {
    return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(first()).toPromise();
}
```

And in my guard:

**auth.guard.ts**

```js
canActivate (next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.auth.isLoggedIn().then((value) => {
        if (value) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['./login']);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it will help you ;)

**EDIT**
I used those tutorials to better understand how to use AngularFireAuth:
https://angularfirebase.com/tag/authentication/ 

And in your case, you have this one:
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/router-guards-to-redirect-unauthorized-firebase-users/